# How to pass nested function parametrs to main function parametrs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function, that makes animation on DOM elements using animate.css when user scrolling the page on certain coordinates. It works perfectly.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.dev-courses__item').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 591) {
            function slideAnimate(name,method){
                if (method === undefined || method == 'default') {
                    method = "slideInLeft";
                }
                $(name).addClass(method);
            };
            slideAnimate('.dev-courses__item-first');
            slideAnimate('.dev-courses__item-second');
            slideAnimate('.dev-courses__item-third');
            slideAnimate('.services-list');
        };
    });
});
```

The goal is to make function, that could be used universally with diferent selectors etc. I tried this:

```
function elemAnimate(selector,position,name,method){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(selector).each(function(){
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + position) {
                function slideAnimate(name,method){
                    if (method === undefined || method == 'default') {
                        method = "slideInLeft";
                    }
                    $(name).addClass(method);
                };
            };
        });
    });
}
elemAnimate('.dev-courses__item', 591, '.dev-courses__item-first');
```

Somehow after function slideAnimate starts to work, nothing happens in console. So i figured out, that i can't pass parametrs from nested function in this way. How to do this correctly?

Comment: So you define `slideAnimate()` but never call it. What is your intent?

Comment: Is `.dev-courses__item` a parent of `.dev-courses__item-first`? Provide some html markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is here:

> #### JavaScript Nested Functions
>
> All functions have access to the global scope.
>   In fact, in JavaScript, all functions have access to the scope "above" them.
>   JavaScript supports nested functions.
>   **Nested functions have access to the scope "above" them.**
>   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Your slideAnimate function is nested in an each function which is nested in the scroll function. Try un-nesting this function.

```
function elemAnimate(selector,position,name,method){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(selector).each(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + position) {
        slideAnimate(name,method);
      }
    });
  });
}

function slideAnimate(name,method){
  $(name).addClass(method === undefined || method === 'default' ? 'slideInLeft' : method);
}
```

Or, if you're only using it to add a class, just get rid of it all together...

```
function elemAnimate(selector,position,name,method){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(selector).each(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + position) {
        $(name).addClass(method === undefined || method === 'default' ? 'slideInLeft' : method);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Also, since you're already using jQuery, have you thought about using jQuery UI? It makes animating things pretty easy.

https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/